# how autopause clementine on skype call?

Tags: skype, voip, clementine

With kde-connect is possible: when come a call, clementine autopause; with VLC is possible: on Skype call the music is autopaused. How can get this in clementine? Autopause music on skype call?

I see in windows is possible with a python script autopause spotify on skype call, but in linux how autopause clementine?

The problem is not, I believe, the configuration of pulseaudio (already working: in VLC). I think I need a (python?) script for Clementine.

Thank you

Comment: There is a bash command "clementine --pause"; so what is the (bash) condition : if (skype ....)?